# Memory allocation and NULL pointer

Tags: c

I am confused from something.

first:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

This type of getting dynamic(heap) memory at **run-time**, not **compile time** like arrays.

`malloc()` may be return `NULL` if there is no memory.

And `NULL` is a `#define` in Standard C Library `#define NULL ((void *)0)`

So, if the `malloc` return `NULL` and it executes at **run-time**, how the compiler will substitute `NULL` with `void *0` and I know that any text substitution happen in **pre-compile phase**

Comment: Strictly speaking, `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`. It returns a null pointer of type `void*`. The macro `NULL` is defined to expand to an expression that evaluates to either a null pointer of type `void*` or else an integer constant (of any integer type) with value 0. It's up to the implementation which. So, the value `malloc` returns on failure compares equal to `NULL` but is not necessarily the same type as `NULL`, and certainly isn't `NULL` itself since `NULL` is a macro and it makes no sense for a function to "return a macro". Functions return values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have it wrong. Imagine the `malloc` function something like this:

```
void *malloc(size_t n)
{
    /* magic */
    return NULL;
}
```

The compiler replaces `NULL` **when that translation unit is compiled**, i.e. when the standard library is compiled so no trace of `NULL` survives past the preprocessor phase. After that point, for what it's worth, malloc just returns numbers.

Comment: Thanks, You drive me to the right concept that I have missed it. :))

Answer (score 1):

After the compiling all the NULL have been replaced by ((void *)0). 
The malloc just return ((void *)0) if there is no memory.

Answer (score 1):

It returns (void*)0 which can be compared somewhere in your source code with a NULL, something like:

```
   int *ptr;
   ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
   if(ptr == NULL) 
       //do something
```

The compiler replaces the `NULL` in the if expression not the `ptr`

Answer (score 0):

The expression `((void *)0)` is the same as plain `0`, it's just typecasted to the type `void *`. That's why you can use e.g. `if (!myPointer)` to check for a pointer not being `NULL`. As `NULL` is the same as palin `0`, it doesn't matter what `NULL` was defined to in `malloc`, as `NULL` *always* has to be `0`.

In older libraries, and still not uncommon, `NULL` used to be defined as plain `0`, and in C++ plain `0` is commonly used instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the fact that `void*` can "carry" pointer of ***any type***.

Examples:

```
void *h;
int *p, **pp;

h = p;
h = pp;
```

so if malloc fails, it will return NULL, which is defined in C as (void*)0, as other answers pointed out.